# C command similar to "if x in list" of Python

Tags: python, c, if-statement, for-loop

In Python we could use `if x in list:` so I was wondering if there's a similar command in C, so that we don't have to go through the whole thing using a `for`.

Comment: You should write a function to loop though the a passed array and return true if found. return false if all elements don't match. Use that function in for.

Answer (score 6):

How can you know whether a value is contained in an array without cycling through it? This is exactly what Python does under the hood. No, there's no magical way to instantly know this.

Comment: I would have put this as a comment, rather than an answer...

Comment: @AChampion, doesn't this answer the question? This is the answer. Sad, but true...

Comment: It does **not** answer the question.

Comment: I knew it wasn't magically just wanted to know if there was a way of not using `for` implicitly

Comment: @Olaf, it does: the question is 'is there a similar command in C so that we don't have to go through the whole thing using a `for`' the answer is _NO_

Comment: @user6122011, you can always use a `while` loop instead :)  Still, in order to search for something, you must cycle through some part of an array.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect answer to me. "Is there a way..." ---> "No."